# Can ndb.KeyProperty reference a base model class when using model inheritance?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have some models that share a common set of properties, which I have defined in a base model class from which other models inherit:

```python
class BaseUser(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class DerivedUserA(BaseUser):
    # some additional properties...

class DerivedUserB(BaseUser):
    # some additional properties...
```

In some other model, I need a reference to any `BaseUser`-derived model:

```python
class MainModel(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind = BaseUser)
```

However, When I try to set a `DerivedUserA` entity key to the `MainModel.user` property, GAE raises a `BadValueError` stating that it is expecting a key with kind `BaseUser` but was given a `DerivedUserA`.

If I remove the `kind` argument from my `MainModel`, it works:

```python
class MainModel(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

I could live with that, but I'd rather have a check in place to make sure that I am not trying to save any kind of entity in the `MainModel.user` property. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PolyModel for datastore inheritance -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass

Comment: Wow, even after spending the last 2 days immersed in ndb's documentation, this class somehow stayed under the radar. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The reason this doesn't work is that the kind parameter to `KeyProperty()` gets translated to a string immediately.
Since it's only a validation feature, we could consider fixing this though.
If you like this idea, you could file a feature request in the tracker: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/list -- this would be less heavyweight than PolyModel (although it seems PolyModel might be what you're looking for anyway).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, PolyModel is what I need because it solves another problem I had with my initial model inheritance, which was that I was not able to perform a query among all BaseUser-derived entities (since they were stored in different datastore tables). I don't think I'd ask you to fix this in KeyProperty, as it seems like PolyModel is really the way to do model inheritance properly.